# how to get Unique values of each column in Mongodb queryset using nodejs

Tags: node.js, mongodb, reactjs, express

I am using nodejs to fetch data from mongodb collection. 
I fetched all data from the collection but I would like to get the result as in the **Expected Result** .
 I got the result as like in the data . I have to get the result of filters I mentioned below along with it. Kindly help me to do this

```
 db.collection('collection_name').find({}).toArray(function(err, items) 
  {
     if(err){
        console.log(err)
        return res.send(500,'something went wrong')
     }
     else{
        res.send({"ISM": items})
     }
  })
```

**Result I got like below :**

```
 {"data": [{
             "CARD_VENDOR": "123",
             "TRANSACTION_AMOUNT": "44938.72",
           },
           {
             "CARD_VENDOR": "012",
             "TRANSACTION_AMOUNT": "1000.00",
           },
           {
             "CARD_VENDOR": "234",
             "TRANSACTION_AMOUNT": "44938.72",
          }]
  }
```

**Expected Reuslt :**

```
   {"data": [{
             "CARD_VENDOR": "123",
             "TRANSACTION_AMOUNT": "44938.72",
           },
           {
             "CARD_VENDOR": "012",
             "TRANSACTION_AMOUNT": "1000.00",
           },
           {
             "CARD_VENDOR": "234",
             "TRANSACTION_AMOUNT": "44938.72",
          }]
  },
  "filters":{
               "CARD_VENDOR" : ["123","012","234"],
               "TRANSACTION_AMOUNT": [44938.72,1000.00]
            }
```

Comment: What result do you get in mongo shell with the command `db.collection('collection_name').findOne().pretty()`?

Comment: am getting error while executing the above query. findOne().pretty() is not a function

Comment: My bad, `findOne()` already prints to console a formatted document, try `db.collection('collection_name').findOne()`

Comment: { "CARD_VENDOR": "123",
  "TRANSACTION_AMOUNT": "44938.72",
 },    ---->>>> first data am getting

Answer (score 0):

To get the desired result, you need to run an aggregate operation on the collection that uses a **[`$facet`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/facet/)** pipeline which allows you to process 
multiple aggregation pipelines within a single stage on the same set of input documents. Each sub-pipeline has its own field in the output document where its results are stored as an array of documents.

In this case your aggregate pipeline would be as follows:

```
const pipeline = [
    { '$facet': {
        'data': [
            { '$match': {} }
        ],
        'filters': [
            { '$group': {
                '_id': null,
                'CARD_VENDOR': { '$push': '$CARD_VENDOR' },
                'TRANSACTION_AMOUNT': { '$push': '$TRANSACTION_AMOUNT' }
            } },
            { '$project': {
                '_id': 0
            } }
        ]
    } },
    { '$addFields': {
        'filters': { '$arrayElemAt': ['$filters', 0 ] }
    } }
]

db.collection('collection_name').aggregate(pipeline, (err, results) => {
    if (err){
        console.log(err)
        return res.send(500, 'something went wrong')
    } else { 
        console.log(results)
        res.send({ "ISM": results })
    }
})
```

Answer (score -1):

u have to manipulate your array

```
data: {
"data": [{
             "CARD_VENDOR": "123",
             "TRANSACTION_AMOUNT": "44938.72",
           },
           {
             "CARD_VENDOR": "012",
             "TRANSACTION_AMOUNT": "1000.00",
           },
           {
             "CARD_VENDOR": "234",
             "TRANSACTION_AMOUNT": "44938.72",
          }],
  "filters":{
               "CARD_VENDOR" : ["123","012","234"],
               "TRANSACTION_AMOUNT": [44938.72,1000.00]
            }
}
```